# Prevent extension automatically added at the end of url (htaccess ?)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

When I go to

```
www.mysite.com/page
```

the browser find

```
www.mysite.com/page.php
```

How to prevent that ?

If I go to

```
www.mysite.com/page
```

I want a 404 error.

And not this page :

```
www.mysite.com/page.php
```

or this :

```
www.mysite.com/page.html
```

**EDIT**

I have something like this in my htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^/?page/(.*)/?$ page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And when font.php exists (method 1) I go to

```
site.com/page/page_name
```

but it doesn't work. I want to obtain this page :

```
 site.com/page.php?name=page_name
```

but I have a good rewrite only if I rename page.php (method 2) file :
I go to :

```
site.com/pages/page_name
```

with this line in htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^/?pages/(.*)/?$ page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and it works. I obtain this page :

```
 site.com/page.php?name=page_name
```

How to do method 1 possible ?

Comment: Do you have anything in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your `.htaccess` or config file :

```
Options -MultiViews
```